# Greyed out menus area @ admin

Tags: wordpress

[image]

One of the recent WP updates caused menus area to be greyed out.. I should have quite few menus available but can see none. For some reason WP built in function doesn't pick them up.

Creation of menu works but they are not fetched.

Latest version of WP

Answer (score 0):

First try to deactivate all plugins and activate default theme, if the issue still remains ( chances are rare ), please report the issue in wordpress forum

Comment: the only plugin i have running is yoast and template doesn't utilise any wordpress methods except for the menu one :S

Comment: try to disable yoast and activate default twentysixteen theme, you can also try to reinstall wordpress, also try to sign out and sign in, it may be your browser add-on, so please restart your browser with all add-ons disabled mode.

Comment: Did all that :P i just looking to downgrade wordpress.. menus do work but not on the backend, will have to debug it myself

Comment: once u figure it out, let us all know what was the cause, thanks

Comment: it is something database related.. probably due to upgrade, sadly.

Comment: don't think so, if its database related, new menu you create can not be vanished from admin screen.

Comment: This was database related. I recommend reinstalling wordpress when such happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it actually looks if no menu has been created so far. If you fill in the menu name field and hit the create menu button, it'll become enabled. User experience could be better.